# Solutions are telling me to update libc6, but it's already updated. How do I fix `GLIBC_2.15' not found?

Tags: linux, debian, steam

I've been trying to run a Garry's Mod server through Open Game Panel all day. I've tried to fix almost all errors, but I can't fix this one.

```
Failed to open dedicated_srv.so (/lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/cmov/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.15' not found (required by bin/dedicated_srv.so))
Add "-debug" to the ./srcds_run command line to generate a debug.log to help with solving this problem
Wed Jul 30 17:47:09 EDT 2014: Server restart in 10 seconds
```

How do I fix this? Libc6 is installed.

Comment: Please include the output of `apt-cache policy libc6:i386
` in your question. Also, as the message says "Add "-debug" to the ./srcds_run command line to generate a debug.log to help with solving this problem". And post the result as well.

Comment: Also, please state what version of Debian you are running. You can paste the output of `lsb_release -a`.

Answer (score 0):

From their [wiki](http://wiki.garrysmod.com/page/Linux_Dedicated_Server_Hosting) in relation to this exact error. Their proposed solution is extracting the files from a .deb archive of a specific/minimal version(2.15) of *glibc* and putting that in the Garry's Mod `bin` directory. The documentation is geared at *Debian* based distributions(partly reproduced):

---

You most likely have outdated *GLIBC* libraries and will need to update them.

To do so, run the following bit of code:

```
wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/e/eglibc/libc6_2.15-0ubuntu10.5_i386.deb
dpkg -x libc6_2.15-0ubuntu10.5_i386.deb tmp/
cd tmp/lib/i386-linux-gnu/
cp * /your-garrysmod-directory/bin/
```